# Connect android APP with mysql server via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, mysql, jakarta-ee, bluetooth

I am new to android development. I want to connect my Android application with mysql server via **Bluetooth**.

Can any one tell me the step by step procedure that how I can send an http request to the bluetooth port on laptop to connect with database.
I am using Java EE on server side. Can I directly connect to the database Or I have to send  request to server (Servlets in this case ) to get data from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' think this is possible, or it's very difficult. You should try pairing with the laptop, gain modem access, use the modem access to the IP you are looking and make the request.